# How do I properly update JWPlayer from 6.x to 7.2.4

Tags: embed, jwplayer

In the previous version of JWplayer 6.12, the following worked flawlessly.

```
<div id="video_0">Loading player</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[// ><!--

        jwplayer('video_0').setup({
            file: '/assets/super-cool-funtime-rah-rah.mp4',
            image: '/assets/super-cool-funtime-rah-rah.jpg',
            width: 600,
            height: 338
        });

//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer-6.12/jwplayer.js"></script>
```

However, upon downloading and unzipping 7.2.4, I attemtped the above. I changed only the version of the JWPlayer that was called.

I've run into a few minor problems:

- clicking the video no longer starts it
- various icons are missing

[image]

My code does not seem so different that what is [exampled](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406723-basic-video-embed#option-3-self-host) from their site. What am I missing? **How do I properly construct the above code, allowing it to play with 7.2.x?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. The issue is likely with how you are hosting the files. Make sure all the contents of the zip are added to the folder where you host jwplayer.js.

What happens if you change the script location to use our CDN? This way you don't have to download any zips or host the player assets yourself. It's also a lot clearer which version you are using:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/7.2.4/jwplayer.js"></script>`

Comment: PS. 7.3.0 is available //ssl.p.jwpcdn.com/player/v/7.3.0/jwplayer.js

Comment: Thank you. That got the video playing and responding properly. The strange marks or missing play  button was caused by CSS being too aggressive. Once I relaxed some CSS rules about font family, those icons reappeared correctly.